# Lazy computation of items in list until required element is found

Tags: list, scala, stream, for-comprehension

I am trying to get my head around making this requirement as efficient as possible, because it is part of a combinatorial problem solver, so every little bit helps in the grand scheme of things.

Lets say I have a list of elements, in this case called transitions.

`val possibleTransitions : List[Transition] = List[...] //coming from somewhere`

I want to perform an (somewhat expensive) computation on each transition, to obtain another object, in this case called a `State`.

The natural way for me to do it is using a `for-comprehension` or a `map`. The former for me is more convenient because I want to filter out a few irrelevant `State` objects, such as those which were already processed earlier.

```
val newStates = for {
     transition <- possibleTransitions
     state <- computeExpensiveOperation(transition)
     if (confirmNewState(state))
} yield state
```

`State` contains a value, lets call it `value()`, which indicates some kind of attractiveness of that state. If the `value()` is very low (attractive) I want to discard the rest of the list and use that. Since `possibleTransitions` could be a very long list (thousands), ideally I avoid doing that `computeExpensiveOperation` if for example the first `State` object already has the `value()` I want.

On the other hand, if I don't find any item with an attractive `value()` I want to keep **all** of them and add them to another list.

`val newPending = pending ++ newStates`

I was trying to use a `Stream` for this, to avoid computing all the values before processing them. If I use `find()` and I don't find the required item then I won't be able to get the items in the stream (since its use-once).

The only thing I can see possible at the moment is to use `possibleItems.toStream()` in the `for-comprehension` and create another collection, iterating through each item one by one until either I find the item (and discard the collection) or no (and use the collection with all items).

Am I missing some smarter more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use lazy views and convert them to a stream to cache the intermediate result, then you can get the information you need:

```
val newStates = for {
     transition <- possibleTransitions.view
     state <- computeExpensiveOperation(transition)
     if (confirmNewState(state))
} yield state
val newStatesStream = newStates.toStream // cache results

val attractive = newStatesStream.find(isAttractive(_))
attractive match {
  case Some(a) => // do whatever
  case None => {
    val newPending = pending ++ newStatesSteam
  }
}
```

As the stream is lazy it will only be computed until the first element is found in the line with `val attractive`. If there is no attractive element the complete stream will be computed and cached and None will be returned.

When computing the new pending elements we can just append this stream to pending. (By the way: pending should probably be a Queue)

Comment: Well the takeWhile will give you an iterator/view that stops after as soon as the condition is not satisfied, so you will only comupte elements up to this point. The toList indeed will compute all these elements. It is often better to compute the elements at some point instead of generating overly complex views. But you can leave it out if you have an other condition and want to continue with the view. You can also convert it to a stream instead that will be lazy but cache the results when they are computed the first time. You just have to know what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Yes exactly. You can also always put println calls in your funtions or for loops to see what is actually evaluated. Not something you should do in real code, but very useful to figure out if everything is as lazy as you wanted it to be.

Comment: Um ok, now I get your question, but takeWhile does not have a side effect, so attractive will just contain the first element from newStates. I'll try to edit it so it does what you need.

Comment: Wow, now this is some advanced use of streams. So is the second stream  `newStatesStream` being populated also when the filter() is taking place? (Since I don't want to compute the thing twice for all elements, once when I am filtering and once when I am taking all the rest).

Comment: Yes, stream keeps all elements it computes, so filter returns a new stream (you could actually think about turning it into a view or iterator again but as it will only contain one element ever it does not mattter). headOption causes the first element of this stream to be computet, which is done by requesting elements from newStateStream until the first one that passes the filter is found. So newStateStream has to compute all elements up to that point and keeps them. This is pretty comfortable, by converting between views/iterators, streams and lists you can control when something is computed.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I think `filter(isAttractvive(_)).headOption` can actually be `find(isAttractive(_))` right? (I think the condition is wrong in your code if you want to fix it)

Comment: yes find is actually the better choice. And yes the condition was a left over from a previous version.